# How can i find best metric

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have many confusion matrices and I need to select best matrix according to precision(TP/TP+FP) and total predictions(TP+TF+FP+FN)..I mean I prefer 8 true in 10 guesses over 2 true in 2 guesses. I couldn't find any metric for this. When i try to find the best precision score.. Sklearn prefer 2 true in 2 guesses (because this meaning %100) instead of 8 true in 10 guesses... How can i find a solution for this